# How to built such list

Tags: list-manipulation

If I give `dim = {2, 2}`,I hope to get

```
Level[Table[{i, j}, {i, First[dim] + 1}, {j, 
   Range[i + 1, First[dim] + 2]}], {-2}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}}

I don't care the position,which mean we can get `{ {1, 3},{1, 4},{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}}` is ok.

If I give `dim = {3, 2}`,I hope to get

```
Level[Table[{i, j}, {i, First[dim] + 1}, {j, 
   Range[i + 1, First[dim] + 2]}], {-2}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}, {3, 
>     5}, {4, 5}}

If I give `dim = {3, 3}`,I hope to get

```
Level[ Table[{i, j, k}, {i, First[dim] + 1}, {j, 
   Range[i + 1, First[dim] + 2]}, {k, 
   Range[j + 1, First[dim] + 3]}], {-2}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 2, 6}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {1,
>      3, 6}, {1, 4, 5}, {1, 4, 6}, {1, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 5}, {2, 
>     3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 6}, {2, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 6}, {3, 5,
>      6}, {4, 5, 6}}

If I give `dim = {3, 4}`,I hope to get

```
Level[Table[{i, j, k, h}, {i, First[dim] + 1}, {j, 
   Range[i + 1, First[dim] + 2]}, {k, 
   Range[j + 1, First[dim] + 3]}, {h, 
   Range[k + 1, First[dim] + 4]}], {-2}]
```

> {{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,5},{1,2,3,6},{1,2,3,7},{1,2,4,5},{1,2,4,6},{1,2,4,7},{1,2,5,6},{1,2,5,7},{1,2,6,7},{1,3,4,5},{1,3,4,6},{1,3,4,7},{1,3,5,6},{1,3,5,7},{1,3,6,7},{1,4,5,6},{1,4,5,7},{1,4,6,7},{1,5,6,7},{2,3,4,5},{2,3,4,6},{2,3,4,7},{2,3,5,6},{2,3,5,7},{2,3,6,7},{2,4,5,6},{2,4,5,7},{2,4,6,7},{2,5,6,7},{3,4,5,6},{3,4,5,7},{3,4,6,7},{3,5,6,7},{4,5,6,7}}

I use $4$ code to face $4$ `dim` curently.I hope to get such function `fun[dim]` to get such list.

Comment: Look up Subsets

Comment: @CarlWoll So..hidden..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Carl Woll hinted at in the comment, for input `{x, y}` you're looking for the `x`-subsets of the list `{1, 2, ..., x + y}`. As you might expect, Mathematica has [a built-in](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsets.html) for that:

```
fun[{x_, y_}] := Range[x + y] ~Subsets~ {x}

fun[{3, 2}]

(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 5},
    {1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}} *)
```